# Why can't I do the counting sort this way?

Tags: arrays, sorting, counting-sort

Counting sort is basically storing the count values in a hash-table sort of structure and then print out the values.

The method I adopted was:

1. Traverse over the input array and store the total counts by `count[arr[i]]++`
2. Again, traverse over the count array and print the `i(th)` index number as many times as the value is there in `count[arr[i]]`. Is this not the correct method?

Most of the places where I read the tutorial, they stored the sum of the counts of previous elements in count array and then place in sorted array by first decreasing the count and then printing it.

Is there anything wrong with my method?

Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that the [Wikipedia article on counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) increments the count in the final loop, instead of decrementing it as you mentioned above. [Geeksforgeek's counting sort page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) decrements the count, as you described. They both sort the input data, but I think the difference is whether identically sorted items are printed in input order or reverse input order (e.g., in my answer below, whether it prints "... dragonfruit watermelon ..." or "... watermelon dragonfruit ...").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is fine when all objects in your array that compare the same are identical. For example, in the array `[ 8, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3 ]`, both `3`s are identical, so it doesn't matter which `3` you print twice in the sorted result. But consider the following JSON array:

```
[
    { "name": "apple", "quantity": 8 },
    { "name": "banana", "quantity": 2 },
    { "name": "dragonfruit", "quantity": 3 },
    { "name": "kiwifruit", "quantity": 5 },
    { "name": "pineapple", "quantity": 4 },
    { "name": "watermelon", "quantity": 3 }
]
```

If you sort this array by quantity, dragonfruit and watermelon will be placed in the same bin, 3. However, when looping over the bins, you can't just print dragonfruit twice to generate the sorted results. Instead, by inserting a loop in the middle of the algorithm to calculate the prefix sum for each bin, it generalizes the algorithm to operate on objects that may differ but compare as equal, and thus it prints dragonfruit once and watermelon once.

The [Variant algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#Variant_algorithms) section of the Wikipedia page for counting sort mentions your optimization, saying that the second and third loops can be combined when the items being sorted are integers.

Comment: Right. Got it. Amazing explanation with dragonfruit and watermelon. Thanks a lot for the help. Really appreciate it. :)

Comment: can you also give me an idea as to why the complexity of counting sort is `O(n+k)`. Shouldn't it be just `O(n)` since we iterate over the input array once, and after that, we iterate over the `count` array which will be `O(k)`.

Comment: @JohnLui As you said, the complexity is `O(n)` followed by `O(k)`, which is `O(n) + O(k)`, which is `O(n+k)`. The Wikipedia page also discusses this in a little more detail under the heading [Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort#Analysis).